# ESP32 cannot serial monitor

Tags: serial, esp32

I use esp32 devkit v1 .
I code follwing this picture.
[image]

```cpp
const int vavle = 1;
int d = 1;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(2000);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println();
  pinMode(vavle,OUTPUT);
  Serial.println(d);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.print("Open Vavle");
  digitalWrite(vavle,HIGH);
  delay(3000);
  digitalWrite(vavle,LOW);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("Close Vavle");
}
```

but serial monitor has error when use serial monitor it show me square .
I confirm select true board rate.
you can solve this problem .

Comment: first thing to remember when posting here is `never post a picture of text unless absolutely necessary` ... please copy your code and paste into your question ... also copy and paste the entire content of the serial monitor

Comment: Side note: You probably want to open or close a _valve_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPIO1 pin you are trying to use with  `const int vavle = 1;` ... `pinMode(vavle, OUTPUT);` *is* the same pin that carries serial data to the PC.

From [the pinout](https://github.com/playelek/pinout-doit-32devkitv1/commit/afa2c642a8e63d73bce5ae93a75672a7755fe363):

[image: DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1 PINOUT with TX0/GPIO1/U0TXD pin highlighted.]

Their schematic link is broken, but if you find schematic for pretty much any similar board using this module you'll see GPIO1/U0TXD connected to a serial transceiver chip which is then connected to the USB port.

You need choose some other pin. There are [pin guides](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-pinout-reference-gpios/) and [official documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/gpio.html) containing the same details that you can use to figure out which GPIO to use.
GPIO numbers 16 through 33 inclusive are all output-capable and seem to have no special requirements, so they make sense to choose from.

Comment: Thank you ,I can solve this problem